# Stanford corenlp: top K ngrams with count

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, n-gram

How to use stanford corenlp to get top K ngrams with their count? I know I can write this code using HashMap or Trai but my corpus is pretty large (200K articles each with avg size 30KB) and I want 5grams, so memory requirement will be huge. Thus I was wondering if I can use corenlp for this purpose. 
So given a corpus it should return only top K ngrams in this format:

word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 : frequency

I don't want any probabilistic model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CoreNLP doesn't have anything to help you store ngrams efficiently.  All it could help you with here would be tokenizing the text (and possibly segmenting the text into sentences, if you care about that).

If your corpus is large enough that you can't just use a hash table to keep the n-gram count, you'll have to use an alternative, more space-efficient representation (e.g. a prefix trie).

For example, I just did a quick test in Clojure where I counted the 5-grams in the Gutenberg King James V Bible.  Using a hashmap to store the counts for 752K distinct 5-grams used 248 MB of heap.  Using a prefix trie to store the counts used 57 MB--a reduction of 77%.

For reference, here's the complete Clojure program using prefix tries:

```
(ns nlp.core
  (:require [clojure.string :as string]))

(defn tokenize
  "Very simplistic tokenizer."
  [text]
  (string/split text #"[\s\:_\-\.\!\,\;]+"))

(defn get-bible-kjv-tokens []
  (tokenize (slurp "/Users/wiseman/nltk_data/corpora/gutenberg/bible-kjv.txt")))

(defn ngrams [n tokens]
  (partition n 1 tokens))

(defn build-ngram-trie [n tokens]
  (->> tokens
       (ngrams n)
       (reduce (fn [trie ngram]
                 (update-in trie ngram #(if % (inc %) 1)))
               {})))

(defn enumerate-trie [trie]
  (if (not (map? trie))
    (list (list trie))
    (apply concat
           (for [[k v] trie]
             (map #(cons k %)
                  (enumerate-trie v))))))

(defn print-trie [trie]
  (doseq [path (enumerate-trie trie)]
    (println (string/join " " (butlast path)) ":" (last path))))


(defn -main []
  (let [ngram-counts (->> (get-bible-kjv-tokens)
                          (build-ngram-trie 5))]
    (print-trie ngram-counts)))
```

And output from the King James V Bible:

```
$ lein run -m nlp.core | sort -r -k7,7 -n ngrams.txt  | head
And it came to pass : 383
the house of the LORD : 233
the word of the LORD : 219
of the children of Israel : 162
it came to pass when : 142
the tabernacle of the congregation : 131
saith the LORD of hosts : 123
it shall come to pass : 119
And the LORD said unto : 114
And the LORD spake unto : 107
```

For some pointers about gaining even more efficiency, the following papers talk about efficient n-gram storage for large corpora:

[ADtrees for Sequential Data and N-gram Counting](http://axon.cs.byu.edu/papers/vandam.smc07.pdf) - Using a custom data structure.

[Faster and Smaller N-Gram Language Models](http://nlp.cs.berkeley.edu/pubs/Pauls-Klein_2011_LM_paper.pdf) - "Our most compact representation can store all 4 billion n-grams and associated counts for the Google n-gram corpus in 23 bits per n-gram, the most compact lossless representation to date"